# Is there a way to send Push Notification to an iPhone from my website?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, mobile-safari, apns-php

I have been trying to figure out a solution to send Push Notification to a device from my website. I have looked into `Pushed`, `OneSignal`, etc. but have been unable to find a solution.

Is it possible through some way through APNS (Apple Push Notification service)?

Thanks

EDIT:
Other questions on SO, either talk about Push Notifications on a web browser on a desktop but I am hoping to find a solution for a browser on an iPhone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Webbased app have push notification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939698/can-a-webbased-app-have-push-notification)

Comment: Specifically you should look at the first link in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4939784/1898563

Comment: I did, but correct me if I am wrong but it talks about Push Notifications in OSX (desktop browsers) instead of iOS (mobile browser).

Comment: Yep, my mistake. I thought it also applied to iOS - realistically there's no reason it shouldn't! The first answer is still relevant though. It seems the only way to currently send push notifications to mobile users is to wrap your site as a native app.

Comment: I am hoping that it could be done through website instead of a native. Those replies are old and may be now there is a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for Websites to send Web Push notifications to Chrome (and soon Firefox) users on Android, however it is not possible to do this on iOS devices.

Apple has not currently indicated whether they plan to add support for this, but there's a good chance they will add it eventually.

Here is a blog post I wrote a few months ago that discusses this limitation: https://onesignal.com/blog/when-will-web-push-be-supported-in-ios/

Comment: @Avery235 unfortunately not. See my updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245096/260491

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018-05-09: While desktop Safari has implemented the proprietary ["Safari Push Notifications" API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/Introduction/Introduction.html), there is still, as of today, no way to send push notifications to iOS' Safari v11.1.

[image: "Notifications for websites do not appear on iOS."]

More info about (Desktop) Safari Push Notifications: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/Introduction/Introduction.html

On the upside, the recently-released [Safari 11.1 does now have support for Service Workers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_11_1.html), which is a prerequisite for [the standards-compliant Web Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API), so it is now *possible* we will see Push API support land in a future version of Safari (including, hopefully, the iOS edition)

More info about Service Workers in Webkit: https://webkit.org/blog/8090/workers-at-your-service/