# iOS web app push notifications - 2017

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Here's my case:

I have developed an app in Cordova which is basicly the mobile version of the client's website. But the app has as extra feature the ability to receive push notifications. All works fine as it should.

But the app got rejected due to

> Your app provides a limited user experience as it is not sufficiently different from a mobile browsing experience

Side note: Few months back I made the same app for a different client but even without the push notifications, no problem. So I guess Apple has made their terms more strict.

Even Apple suggests to rather use a web app. So my big question is: 
**Is it possible to have a web app for iOS that also receives the push notifications**?

I've been searching around the web for the past few days and I've read a lot of blogs and posts on the issue but most of them are almost over a year old.

Does any of you have more info on this or even have a better solution to the app rejection?

Comment: No, there's no way to send web push notifications to iOS at the moment. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920874/51387)

Answer (score 3):

To whom it may concern:

This is still not possible (June 2017).

Comment: I wrote [some paragraphs](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/06/lets-ask-apple-to-add-web-push-notifications-to-ios/) that any developer can copy and submit to Apple through their bug tracker in order to ask for this feature and make some pressure.

Comment: @collimarco Ah perfect! They will need some pressure indeed.