# Push notification from web browser ios

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I struggle to find a solution how can I send push notification to a mobile device from my web application. For Android there is no problem I use One Signal service. Is there a way for Iphone devices also

Thank you in advance!

Comment: One signal also supports iOS notifications

Comment: But only for Safari on Mac

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939698/how-can-a-web-application-send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices - here can be answer on your question

Answer (score 0):

Onesignal supports iOS platform too.

Using the browser app, you can call [OneSignal API](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/onesignal-api) which in turn will trigger push notification to iOS app.

You need to have an iPhone app in conjunction with your browser app using which device token can be registered.

Official link : [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/ios-sdk-setup)

Video tutorial : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmJ6xSntZjo)

Comment: But only for native. I am asking for a browser based app.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications have been announced for iOS 16.4 which should be released March 2023.  I've written a [tutorial](https://devtails.xyz/@adam/how-to-setup-web-push-notifications-in-ios-safari) showing how to implement them in a web app.