# Web Push Notifications not appearing when tab closed

Tags: macos, google-chrome, push-notification, web-push

My chrome push notifications work when the browser tab is open but not when it is closed. From what I understand the notification should appear even when the tab is closed.

I have verified that the notifications are allowed for the site

[image]

How can I debug why push notifications are not working when the tab is closed?

Btw I am on a mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing two different technologies:

- using the **Notification API alone**, as you do, will show the notification only when the page is open
- in order to show notifications when a website is closed you need to use **Service Workers + Push API + Notification API** as I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939698/how-can-a-web-application-send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices/34920874#34920874)