# Chrome extension Desktop notification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension for desktop notification.Is there any way by which I can close the desktop notification after a specified time ?

Comment: [Chrome supports desktop notifications natively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can close it by running `window.close()` from notification's javascript (assuming your notification is a separated HTML file). So something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.close();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have a reference of the notification object, you can use *notification.cancel* instead:

```
  setTimeout(function() { 
      notification.cancel(); 
  }, 5000);
```

References:

- [Chrome extension development: auto close the notification box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732031/chrome-extension-development-auto-close-the-notification-box)
- http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification

Answer (score 1):

for me this worked

```
setTimeout(function() {
    notification.close();
}, 2000);
```