# Chrome extension development: auto close the notification box

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, auto-close

After doing something I run this code:

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
   'icon.png',  // icon url - can be relative
  'Done!',  // notification title
  'Just updated your list!'  // notification body text
   );
  notification.show();
```

which of course pops up a notification into the users screen.

It there anyway to time this notification so that it auto-closes in X amount of seconds?

Thanks!
R

Comment: Please see this answer for detailed description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51572172/3089950

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `notification.cancel();`

Comment: I like the `notification.cancel();` because it can be called from the same function that creates the notification.

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly like I wanted it to!

Comment: There might be a update for the API, you should use notification.close() now.

Answer (score 9):

```js
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification('images/icon-48x48.png',"This is       Title","Biswarup Adhikari Notification");
notification.show();
setTimeout(function(){
notification.cancel();
},2000);
```

Chrome notification will close automatically after 2000 milli sec or 2 sec.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be able to call `window.close()` from inside the notification's HTML page. That will close the notification.

To close at a certain time, calling something like `setTimeout( function () { window.close(); }, timeInMicroseconds);` should be effective.

Comment: Thanks you! That hits the spot!

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(title, message, icon) {
try {
    icon = icon || 'src/img/icons/icon48.png';
    var self = this;
    var isClosed = false;
    var notificationId = "posting_" + Math.random();

    chrome.notifications.create(notificationId, {
        type: "basic",
        title: title + "!",
        message: message,
        iconUrl: icon
    }, function (nId) {
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!isClosed)
            chrome.notifications.clear(notificationId, function (wasCleared) {
            });
    }, 3000);
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
```

}

ok,  when i created notification remeber the id `notificationId` and settimeout clear this id

Comment: please also explain what you changed and why

Answer (score -1):

```
//Use requireInternaction and set it to true for notification to not to auto-hide.

function showNotification() {
    var options = {
        body: 'The Subtitles will Go Here',
        requireInteraction: true
    };

    if (window.Notification && Notification.permission !== "denied") {
       Notification.requestPermission(function (status) {  // status is "granted", if accepted by user

var n = new Notification('Title', options);
        });
     }

   }
```