# Closing a chrome-extension notification using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an google-chrome-extension which has html notifications. There will be a "close" button on it. Is there anyway to make the notification close on the button click? I have already tried window.close(), but it does not seem to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.close(); should work for you, check out the [Chrome/Silver Bird code](https://github.com/cezarsa/silver_bird) as there is a close link on these that works and might point you towards what you're doing differently...

similiar questions which might help you at 
[Closing popup window created by Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950981/closing-popup-window-created-by-google-chrome-extension) 
[Chrome extension development: auto close the notification box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732031/chrome-extension-development-auto-close-the-notification-box)