# Google Chrome extension to close notification after user click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The Chrome extension works fine. My problem is that the notification closes in 7 seconds. I want for the user click to close the notification.

```
function engine(){
    var latestId;
    var ids;
    var messages = [];
    var newmessage = [];

    $.get('http://localhost/site/json.php',function (data){
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        messages = json;
        ids = json[0].id;
        if(latestId == ids){
            //no update
        }else if(latestId === undefined){
            var run = {
                type: "basic",
                title: "Title",
                message: "Some message",
                iconUrl : "icon.png",
            };

            chrome.notifications.create(run);
        }    
    });
}
```

Comment: Unsure what you're asking. Do you want the notification to close whenever you click on it, or do you want to keep it from hiding after 7 seconds and close ONLY on user interaction?

Answer (score 3):

First create your notification and give it a notificationID parameter to close it later.

```
var notification = {
    type:"basic",
    title:"News From Us!",
    message:"Google Chrome Updated to v50!",
    iconUrl:"assets/images/icon.png"
};
chrome.notifications.create("notfyId",notification);
```

On notification click you can close notification using its id (which is "notfyId")

```
function forwardNotfy(){
    chrome.notifications.clear("notfyId");
    window.open(url); //optional
 }

 chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(forwardNotfy);
```

Now, when you click your notification it'll close.

Comment: window.location not working, however window.open does

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `notification.close();`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    notification.close();
}, 2000);
```

Demo:

```js
// request permission on page load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});

function notifyMe() {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
      icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
      body: "Hey there! You've been notified!x",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");      
    };
    
    setTimeout(function() {
    notification.close();
}, 2000);
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="notifyMe()">
  Notify me!
</button>
```

JSBin Demo

Comment: notification.cancel is not a function write in consol ? Can you please example code write here?

Comment: @Arokiyanathan: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Please [edit] your answer, and put the link into it. Also please try to make your answer detailed and clearly. See: [answer]

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently only implemented in the beta channel, and not in the latest version of chrome. See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) for details.

When it is implemented, you will be able to use `requireInteraction : True` like:

```
var run = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Title",
    message: "Some message",
    iconUrl : "icon.png",
    requireInteraction : True,
}
```

to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

**notification.close()** is used to close any notification.

For more information please see the below code-

**To create the notification:**

```
var notification = new Notification('OnlineOfferPrice', {
    icon: 'icon.png',
    body: "Test Message",
});
```

If you want to perform operation on notification click please use the below code. After your business logic it will automatically close-

```
notification.onclick = function () { 
    //write your business logic here.
    notification.close();
};
```

If notification is not clicked and you want to close it automatically after 6 seconds-

```
setTimeout(function() { notification.close(); }, 6000);
```