# AJAX notification when page has changed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp-classic, notifications

Heylo guys,

i have a page that gets new content using AJAX/ASP (a shoutbox-like type of thing). 
i was wondering if its possible to create a popup window to notify that the page has changed (a new message) when the page is not focused (user in other window/tab)?

thx.

Comment: I doubt you'll get anything better than Facebook Chat has - make a Ding! sound, and change the window title to show a new message has arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [this page](http://0xfe.blogspot.com/2010/04/desktop-notifications-with-webkit.html) and see if it works for you. It has code for doing desktop notifications in Chrome. I don't think there is a cross browser way of doing it.

**edit:**
I got the above link from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, the page is changed by your code right? then you can popup the window in the ajax callback function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
   // popup the window here.
  }
});
```