# What ways are out there to display a desktop notification from a web app?

Tags: web-applications, notifications, desktop

What I would like to do is show a toaster like notification preferably but any method of "pushing" updates to the desktop is interesting.

Thanks

Comment: To show notification from a website as a popup you can use ***alert***.

Comment: @harry. Thanks, but I am looking for a solution that will be good ui practice as well.

Comment: how to do the same with windowsforms in asp.net? @reshefm

Answer (score 144):

Below is a working example of desktop notifications for Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari, copied from [Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example/13328513#13328513).
Try it live [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ziwod/2/edit?html,js,output).

```js
// request permission on page load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});

function notifyMe() {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
      icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
      body: "Hey there! You've been notified!",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");      
    };

  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>
```

---

More information about how this works in my answer to [Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example/13328513#13328513).

Comment: @Dan: Using `window.open` you are passing a specific URL to be opened on click. Is there any method to open the tab which throws the notification?

Comment: This was obsoleted. The better example would be on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification).

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil: Thanks, I've updated my answer. Okay to delete both our comments?

Comment: how to do the same with deskto app (windows form)?

Comment: Thanks for the informative post. It helped me a lot to understand this notification structure.

Comment: I tested the live on JSBin, It doesn't work in Chrome V.63 while it works in Firefox properly.

Comment: copied & pasted = worked perfectly on chrome, firefox, opera and edge! doesn't work on ie though. (upvoted)

Answer (score 2):

On Chrome, you can achieve something like this using Desktop notification. See [Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) for example.

If your users have growl installed on their machine you should check out [growl developer page](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/introduction.php)