# How to show notifications in web application?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, notifications

I am working on a web application in which I need to show the notification to user.
However, user should not be interrupted because of that like showing an alert kind of things.
Can you please guide me how can i implement this thing which should work in all the browsers and also using javascript/HTML ?
I have found some solutions as under:
1) Giving a control on every page (may be button), which will show the user all the events generated so far.
2) Putting an div on every page which will continuously update as and when events occurred

Please help...

thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you please tell us which technologies you are using and notifications is from client side or else server side?

Comment: Notifications are coming from server side.As when events generate ar server side, client will be notified.I am using Javascript at client side.

Comment: Have look this link http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/web-notifications

Comment: Thanks...
But it doesn't seems to be working in FF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try one of these :

/1. jgrowl :

http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html

/2. jquery notification plugin :

http://www.plumtheory.com/demos/notification-center/light/

Answer (score 1):

If you want your notifications to be visible even when the user is in another tab, or in another application than the browser, then you can use desktop notifications. These work however only for [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) right now. I've listed an example on [how to use Chrome desktop notifications in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a summary section at the bottom of the web page which can be updated with the necessary user alerts.

Are you looking at how to implement it? If so, post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer...
Can you please give me an example of any site which is using this thing for the notifications ???