# Zclip working on jsfiddle but not working locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle, zclip

Its strange ::

> Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sxeCM/4/  [ Working ]

Locally having the same code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#copy').zclip({
            path:'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:$('div#description').text()
        });
    });
    </script>
    <a id='copy' href="#">Copy</a>
    <div id='description'>this seems awesome</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Its not working locally but working as expected on jsfiddle. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like one of those security restrictions against `file:///` URLs. I recently played with desktop notifications in Webkit, and they just [won't launch on local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092885/what-ways-are-out-there-to-display-a-desktop-notification-from-a-web-app/13328397#13328397), but would work fine if the file was accessed over `http://`.

Comment: Let me try.. although - I would say its seriously lame by not mentioning it in the documentation.

Comment: Awesome.. it worked over http. I am angry over - the developers of `zclip`. I have wasted a whole day on this.