# Copy to clipboard - Work on JSFiddle but not in local

Tags: jquery, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to implement a code to copy the contents of an item in the clipboard. It work on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj7ZX/5/)

**HTML**

```
<p id="description">Text to copy</p>
<a href="#" id="copy">Click here to copy</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#copy').zclip({
        path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $('#description').text(),
        beforeCopy: function () {
            $('#description').css('background', 'yellow');
        },
        afterCopy: function () {
            $('#description').css('background', 'green');
        }
    });
});
```

But if I create html file with the same content, it doesn't work ...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="description">Text to copy</p>
<a href="#" id="copy">Click here to copy</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#copy').zclip({
        path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $('#description').text(),
        beforeCopy: function () {
            $('#description').css('background', 'yellow');
        },
        afterCopy: function () {
            $('#description').css('background', 'green');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why ?

Comment: There is one  ! Look at the begining "It work on JSFiddle"

Comment: Your website's link not JSFiddle

Comment: ...okay so it work online but not in local...

Comment: did you accidentally disabled js?

Comment: I don't think so because some test like `alert` work good

Comment: It work in local for you ?

Comment: `zclip` does not work locally due to security/developer restrictions. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330472/zclip-working-on-jsfiddle-but-not-working-locally

Comment: However, I searched on stackoverflow. What I do with this post?