# Notification popup doesn't appear in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, html5-notifications

I am trying to do a gmail similar type desktop notification . I am facing the difficulty to change the notification permission in chrome. The permission always shows denied in console if i use **window.Notification.permission**. If i manually change the permission in google chrome settings -> privacy -> content settings -> Notifications as "Allow all sites to show desktop notifications" from "Do not allow any site to show desktop notifications" . Now i am able to get desktop notification normally. But I need an alert to asking a permission if the browser have setting as "Do not allow any site to show desktop notifications" , then i need to choose   allow from the popup in order to change the setting as "Allow all sites to show desktop notifications". The problem is permission is not changed if i do like this even the permission alert is not coming . The permission checking script follows

```
if(Notification.permission == 'denied'){
                 Notification.requestPermission(function (status){
                        console.log("Reaching here");
                        Notification.permission = status;
                     });
            }
```

The popup for requesting permission to allow or disallow notifications is not occurred. Thanks in advance for suggesting me a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be a problem with your script.

It's part of the standard that when the `permission` is set to `denied` you can NEVER show the popup which asks "Do you want to allow... to send desktop notifications ?". This popup is used only in the case the `permission` is set to `default`, which in fact means that the user doesn't care and you should ask him if he wants them or not.

This is the conditionnal I use :

```
Notification['permission'] !== 'granted' && Notification['permission'] !== 'denied'
```

Because the `default` value isn't supported by all browsers. Plus the `permission` attribute was not implemented prior to chrome 32, that's why you should access it using the square brackets.

In fact you could also remove the `denied` part in my conditionnal, because it won't do anything if the permission is denied. You can refer to [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications) to get more information on compatibility and things like that.

Comment: Yes @Depado ,You are right. I figure it out later. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually I hope the Notification API will get some extra attention now that it's a standard. Plus I hope they will restore the fact that we can put html inside it. (+ Edited the answer to give extra information)

Answer (score 1):

Issue of not opening dialog box is http. Chrome desktop notification work only on https protocol.

I have faced this issue and I have spend many time to solved that. Finally I got solution using https.

Here I shared code so you can run on https and it will working fine.

```
enter code here
       // request permission on page load
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      if (!Notification) {
        alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
        return;
      }

      if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
        Notification.requestPermission();
    });

    function notifyMe() {
      if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
        Notification.requestPermission();
      else {
        var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
          icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
          body: "Hey there! You've been notified!",
        });

        notification.onclick = function () {
          window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");      
        };

      }

    }

    notifyMe();

    Call notifyMe(); to show notification
```