# Ask for permissions again after they have been denied in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification

I'm trying to ask the user for permission again after he has denied permissions the first time. So if he click on my button enable notifications, after he has denied them the first time the browser should ask him again. According to this answer:

[Notification popup doesn't appear in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472601/notification-popup-doesnt-appear-in-chrome/25119803#25119803)

It's not possible, but I don't know if this has changed since 2014.

```
if (window.Notification || Notification.permission === 'denied') {
   Notification.requestPermission(status => {
   // do something
   });
}
```

Comment: `but I don't know if this has changed since 2014` so, have you tried? I doubt that it would have changed, but it's simple to try :p - anyway, do what I saw just the other day - if you see it's denied, then display a popup saying what to do if you change your mind

Comment: My code you see is what I have tried, Idk if there was another way to do it to force asking for permission again. Displaying the popup sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 2):

When `Notification.permission` value is `denied` it is by design that the `Notification.requestPermission` pop-up does NOT show up. The pop-up shows up only when the permission value is `default`. If the value is denied, it needs to be reset in browser's settings, e.g. `chrome://settings/content/notifications`

Comment: So, i stick with the question. It can be impressive to ask a visitor on the first time and i figure it can raises skeptical eyebrows. I can imagine a scenario when the user still makes an account, and where there is asked in the account section: Click here to receive realtime updates about your order processing. would be cool if the client changes his mind.

Comment: @HenryW I guess you'd have to provide instructions (e.g. text + screenshot) of how to reset it in the browser settings, e.g. for chrome under `chrome://settings/content/notifications`

Comment: Is there any link like this one for Chrome ANDROID?

Comment: @jobima in chrome next to the address bar tap on more (3 vertical dots), then settings then sit3 settings then notifications