# How to give access to camera onclick in java script

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, camera

Im working on mobile site that has a page that open the camera and scan qr code to do an action.
There are users that press deny to popup of access/deny camera on accident and dont know to fix this (reload not fix this always - sometimes its block camera to browser).
How to do a button that alert this popup again? (Ask permission again).
(Must support iOS & android)
Or even if its possible to open access to camera automatically?
Im working in pure java script, html.

Im tried to search google and didn’t found working solution.
I know there is something like getMediaUser but Im really need explained solution or example…

Hope for answers!

Comment: You can't re-ask for permission the user has denied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ask for permissions again after they have been denied in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924686/ask-for-permissions-again-after-they-have-been-denied-in-browser)