# desktop notification using javascript in windows form

Tags: javascript, c#, notifications

i am new to this and i am creating simple application in which i click a button and a notification on desktop should be displayed. i am doing this in `windows form c#`

the error is " `NullReferenceException was unhandled`

i have one button `Notify` in form1. i have tried this:

form1.cs

```
     public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
                webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            }

            private void btnNotify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("notifyMe");
            } 

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CurrentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            webBrowser1.Navigate(Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory,"HTMLPage1.html"));
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
```

code for HTMLPage1.html :

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
    });

    function notifyMe() {
    if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.');
    return;
    }

    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
    else {
    var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
    icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
    body: "Hey there! You've been notified!",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
    window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");
    };

    }

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

even if i simply put `alert("Hi")` in notifyMe() function, nothing else. still it displays the same error.

[image: ErrorMsg]

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NullReferenceException? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: private void btnNotify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript`("notifyMe")`;
            } @christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your html and scripts in the debug directory if they are not automatically placed. Thats where getcurrentdirectory() hits.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code.. you should use

```
document.attachEvent('DOMContentLoaded', function () {..
```

Instead of

```
document.addEventListener("..
```

That worked from here...read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695383/4155741

you should also remove that comma at the end of  **.. body: "Hey there! You've been notified!",** as it prevent the script from be compiled.

Comment: mhh i wonder!! remove `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`

Comment: you will get a prompt showing which line have a problem, After fixing everything in your code i still got `Notification` is not defined , so assuming you have defined it **elsewhere** i replaced the function block with an alert, that way i knew the fuction is getting called on button click. remember any error in the script or a failed fuction execution will cause the `NullReferenceException` while invoking.

Comment: well i have put simple alert but nothing.. nothing happening. this is so frustrating..

Comment: script is working fine in JSfidle. so i guess no error in script

Comment: One more thing, since you are using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` I hope you have the up to date html in the debug directory, vs didn't seem to copy it to debug directory when debugging for some reason... And I had to place it manually.

Comment: so now what i have to do?

Comment: i have created new form. using one button. on its click i am calling javascript function `Hi()` with only one alert in it. and it says the same error. i think the problem is in calling the javascript function.

Comment: You have to put your html and scripts in the debug directory if they are not automatically placed.  Thats where getcurrentdirectory() hits.

Comment: Bingo.. yes i figured it out. but no debug folder creating in my solution. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972224/debug-folder-not-present-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81144/discussion-between-dinav-ahire-and-eliya-konzo).

Comment: I have a message for you in chat