# Debug folder not present in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a Windows form application in Visual Studio 2013.

In my scene, I have one button and on click of that button I have a `javascript function` to call. this JavaScript function is in `HTMLPage1.html`

Now if I have to access it the page should be added in `debug` folder as I watched in one tutorial. But in my case `debug` folder is not adding when I create a `new project`

it shows following error.

[image: Exception message]

Any idea how to do this. and even if how to call html page JavaScript function without this `debug` folder?

Comment: it seems like i cant call javascript function on buttong click in winforms because of this problem.

Comment: what do you want to do ?? call a javascript function in your C# back-end code ?

Comment: yes. on button click. but in `winforms`

Comment: Nai med padega humara

Comment: padega padega.. flow is simple. i have to code javascript in html page and using webBrowser and then calling that script on button click event by using method `webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("ScriptName")`

Comment: but it is simple visual studio 10 as there is debug folder present in solution explorer. But not in vs13.

Comment: I have not worked before this `winForms` so cant help you ! But I guess u figured this out in your other question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81229/discussion-between-dinav-ahire-and-abhishek-ghosh).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are in release mode. Go to `Build` > `Configuration Manager` and change `Active solution configuration` to `debug.`

Comment: it is alredy `debug` there

Comment: any other possibilities sir?