# Google Rich Notifications, best way to click to open a notifications specific url?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm developing a chrome extension and i'm currently making use of the chrome.notifications API.
The behaviour i need, is to have each notification have a specific and possibly different url to open on click.

With the chrome rich notifications i can create a notification via `chrome.notifications.create(string notificationId, NotificationOptions options, function callback)` but the Options parameter doesn't allow me to send in extra information, like the url i want it to open.

What's the best way to do this?

I could use the `chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(string notificationId) {...})` function with the notificationId and find out what the url is, but either i make another call to the server to figure it out (which i want to avoid) or i could probably store it in the local storage, but the easier way would be just to create the notification with that information when i receive it from the server, instead of storing it or getting it again from the server only when the click happens.

I could use the Html5 Notifications, and do something like this:

```
var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
  icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
  body: "Hey there! You've been notified!",
});

notification.onclick = function () {
  window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");
```

but i would lose the RichNotification features and i'm also trying to avoid going that way.

Is there a simpler or better way?

Cheers

Comment: Yes, local storage is on of my ideas since i don't have a persistent background page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notificationId` can be an arbitrary string, so you could use the URL as the `notificationId` in [`chrome.notifications.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create). If the URL is not necessarily unique, add a prefix or suffix. If you want to have more parameters (e.g. different actions for each button), then serialize the object (e.g. using `JSON.serialize`).
All events listener (onClosed, onClicked, onButtonClicked) receive the `notificationId` as a parameter, so it's easy to get the original data back.

Comment: Yes, that's a great simple idea. I passed a Json as the id and then i can do whatever i need when the notification is clicked, thx