# Sending browser notification to specific users (web)

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, push-notification, notifications

I would want to send out notifications to the list of users from database.

I found a solution to send push notifications:

```
// request permission on page load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
if (!Notification) {
alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
return;
}

 if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
Notification.requestPermission();
});

function notifyMe() {
if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
Notification.requestPermission();
else {
var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
  icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
  body: "Hey there! You've been notified!",
});

notification.onclick = function () {
  window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");      
};

}

}
```

(Source: [Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) )  How can i configure it to send specific notifications to specific users ? 
Let us assume that I want to send notifications to all users of the table user_notification. 
I tried using

```
<?php
$sqx = "SELECT * FROM `user_js` "; 
 ?>
```

in the code but it does not help either

Comment: @JayBlanchard I dont agree. I see this as a 'specific coding issue'. I just dont know how to configure it

Comment: When I marked this as "too broad" there was no code in the question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard.. Thank you for your patience. 
Now, would you help me find a solution ?

Comment: Currently there is no way to directly push web notifications from the server to the client. You can only use websockets or long polling ajax to connect to the server and then make a new notification object.

Comment: There is currently a Notifications Service Worker RFC in draft to make it possible to directly push notifications to clients, even if the website is not open in the moment.

Answer (score 2):

**step 1** : try adding the following into your HTML response :

```
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>
```

**step 2** : if you can see the button and you get a notification when you click on it, try to move on and trigger it as soon as the page loads.
see if this link will help you : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

principally, this should work :

```
<body onload="notifyMe()">
```

**step 3** : if all works well, you'll have to add a PHP condition that will add this "onload=..." only to the users you want.

Comment: Although not what I was looking for, it can be a good temporary fix. I have implemented it at [www.zigsaw.in/jobs] in userlogin as a job seeker. 
Do have a look :)
Thank you for the suggestion