# How can remove all Chrome notifications in load view with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

This is my code to show notification in Google Chrome.

How can I close notification in code?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.');
    return;
  }
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});

function notifyMe() {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('test', {
      icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
      body: "test",
    });
    notification.onclick = function() {
      window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. The notification will be closed by the user or not - the window can be closed if you save the handle `var w = window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037","_blank");` using `w.close();` unless loading a different origin blocks you from accessing the window again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple, every notification object has `close()` method you need to just push them on to an array and call `close()` on each one of them before window close

```
var notify=[];

for(var i=0; i<=4;i++){
  var notification = new Notification('test', {
  icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
  body: "test"+i
  });                                  //create some notifications
  notify.push(notification);
}

function removeAllNotifys()
{
  for(var i=0; i<notify.length;i++){
    notify[i].close();                 //remove them all  
  }
}

window.onbeforeunload = removeAllNotifys;
```

You can also associate `removeAllNotifys()` on some button click to clear all notification or use setTimeout to remove them say after 2 seconds .