# How to remove all chrome notifications on one click in website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[This is link I used to insert notifications in my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)

Now suppose there are 20 notifications in my app which are showing in set of 3,

[Like this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXnkf.png)

Now I need to remove all these notifications on single click.

Is there any way I can implement this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605653/how-can-remove-all-chrome-notifications-in-load-view-with-javascript/40608565

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much!!