# How to navigate to the tab that generates desktop notification

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications

I am using the code found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/5937428) to generate a desktop notification, but I can't figure out how to get it to take me back to the page when I click on the notification.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclick):

> The default behavior is to move the focus to the viewport of the notification's related browsing context.

But when I click on the notification without specifying an `onclick`, it just closes the notification. When I try using `window.focus()` it also just closes the notification.

You can see my altered code [here](http://jsbin.com/kegixasibi/edit?html,js,output). I added a `setTimeout` to allow me to switch tabs before it fires, and removed the `onclick` event.

I'm using chrome 59 on macOS serria if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have put your `onclick` handler outside the timeout on the object `notification` and declaring `notification` reference inside timeout, so you are not getting the proper object while assigning the `onlick`, instead do it inside timeout.

It is not working in jsBin for some reason (may be they are creating nested window or iframe, because `window.parent.parent.focus();` works) but it will work in your case, just try it! I have just modified your code, or here is a new [bin](http://jsbin.com/harejakime/edit?html,js,output)