# webkitNotifications.requestPermission() typeError

Tags: safari, webkit, notifications, desktop, typeerror

I get a weird error when I try to ask for permissions for displaying desktop notifications on Safari I get a typeError. I got a button which triggers `window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission()' onclick.

HTML Code:

```
<button id='btn'>Request Permissions</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var btn = document.getElementById( 'btn' );
btn.onclick = function () {
    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
}
```

This snippet works fine on Chrome, but on Safari throws a typeError.

The website runs on localhost.

Comment: *TypeError* is a value type issue. Shouldn't Safari `requestPermission` expect a callback?

Comment: Yes actually you are right. I assumed that it would be more handy if I didn't give a callback at all instead of giving an empty function :P. Unfortunately Safari doesn't accept that.

Comment: This answer works in safari and chrome
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328513/218418