# Is it possible to put links in chrome desktop notifications

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension which displays desktop notifications on particular events.  I am receiving and displaying the desktop notifications just fine, but the problem comes when I try to put attribute tags into notification.  Instead of being the text as tags to be appended to the notififcation's DOM, Chrome seems to just interpret them as plaintext, resulting in the content of the notification being just html source code.

Is there any way that I can have the body of my messages be appended as HTML instead of just text or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible, but now it's not. But you could use a "Rich Notification" and put the link on a button. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328513/488287 for details.