# How to create Javascript/Chrome notifications that are shown over fullscreen applications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, growl

I have a web application (HTML5, CSS3, JQuery) that displays notifications using both methods: a growl-like jquery plugin (javascript+html), or using the Chrome notification API (only if you are using Chrome).

What I want is to create a javascript growl-like notification that is shown over all the other windows in the screen, even if you have another application focused in fullscreen mode.

I think that this is not possible with javascript because probably it is restricted to the browser window, but maybe with the Chrome notification API it could be done (this notifications popup over other applications, if they are not in fullscreen mode).

Recently Chrome updated its browser so that the notifications are not shown if you have an application in fullscreen. In general it is a good update but if you want to show the notification even if you are in a fullscreen app, how do you do that? Can the final user of the web application change the behaviour of this notifications and make them appear always?

PD: if there is another browser technology that allows this kind of notifications, please tell me.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example

Comment: Thanks for the example, thats the way I'm displaying the Chrome notifications now, but what I want is that the notifications could be shown over all the active windows, even if they are in fullscreen.

Comment: @FerNando I know that Firefox version <13 display notifications that are shown over fullscreen applications. That's why we are still using Firefox v12. Maybe it's an option for you too.
  It's a pity that with Chrome and the latest versions of Firefox fullscreen overlay is not working.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware this is not possible, certainly not as any sort of cross-browser solution.