# Trying to create a google notification, Uncaught TypeError error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the new chrome notifications, nothing fancy just trying to a basic one to work, but i keep getting

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined**

I think its the manifest but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Javascript

```
var id= 0;

var opt={
type:"basic",
title:"Hello",
message:"world",
iconUrl:"Google.png"
}


function creationCallback(id) {
console.log("Succesfully created " + id + " notification");
}


function createnot()
{

chrome.notifications.create(id, opt, creationCallback);
id++;
}
```

manifest

```
{
    "name": "Notification API Sample",
    "description": "Tests the notification API",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "version" : "0.1",

    "permissions" : [
    "notifications"
    ]
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="note.js"></script>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="meh" onclick="createnot()"/>
 <footer>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it ***`chrome.appNotifications`*** ?

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html => What version of chrome do you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example => have you tried ***`window.webkitNotifications.createNotification`***

Comment: version: 30.0.1599.22 beta-m.

window.webkitNotifications.createNotification is deprecated
 now.

Comment: The `chrome.notifications` api should be called from the background page of the extension. Your manifest doesn't include any scripts or pages. How are you running your javascript?

Comment: through the webpage, on the button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
    "name": "Notification API Sample",
    "description": "Tests the notification API",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "version" : "0.1",

    "permissions" : [
    "notifications",
    "http://*/*" // add this if your html file is a webpage not a page in extension.

    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false // add this line if you use event page.
    }

}
```

Your manifest.json needs the information of "background" like this.

Also, if your html page is a webpage not a page in extension itself,
You need to give a permission for it.

```
var id = "0";
```

It may not make much difference but,I think notification id needs to be a string.

```
chrome.notifications.create(string notificationId, NotificationOptions options, function callback)
```

**+++Edited+++**

***foo.js***

```
$(function(){

var test = $("#test");

test.click(function () {


    chrome.notifications.create(
        'id1',{   
            type:"basic",
            title:"Hello",
            message:"world",
            iconUrl:"Google.png"
        },

        function() { 

        } 

    );


});

});
```

***foo.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="test">This is a test.</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Notification API Sample",
    "description": "Tests the notification API",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "version" : "0.1",

    "permissions" : [
    "notifications"
    ]

}
```

I think this is the simplest way if the html page is in extension.

You need these files. You don't even need background.js for this.

1.manifest.json

2.foo.html

3.foo.js

Comment: Why would I'd need to be a string? That makes no sense.

Comment: chrome.notifications.create(string notificationId, NotificationOptions options, function callback)

Because it says so.

Comment: Is the html file a specific page on the web?

Comment: is locally hosted.
new manifest.
 "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
 "page": ["jsTest.html"],
        "persistent": false // add this line if you use event page.
    }

Comment: ok so i used your code, the extension has the rights because it comes up in the list of allowed sites for notifications, but i still get  Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Comment: I tested my code before I posted it. So, it should work. If it doesn't, you need to provide enough information.

Comment: >it comes up in the list of allowed sites for notifications.

So, you mean the notification shows up, but you still get an error?

Comment: It works, no idea why it didn't before but just tried it again and it does work.
Thank you very much.

Comment: oh great! I'm glad to hear that!