# How to create a notification chrome extension?

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

i want to create a google chrome extension that notify user when a new record in the mysql DB is added ! there is someone who can help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: [Chrome supports desktop notifications natively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example).

Comment: Did you find it working? Can you share your source code?

Comment: Well. You could use a php script to communicate to the mySQL DB and make an ajax call to the php script from your chrome extension

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please refer to this page.

> Use the chrome.notifications API to create rich notifications using
> templates and show these notifications to users in the system tray.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/

```
chrome.notifications.create(
  "name-for-notification",
  {
    type: "basic",
    iconUrl: "image.jpeg",
    title: "This is a notification",
    message: "hello there!",
  },
  function () {}
);
```

You can create notification like this.

**EDIT:** Please do not forget to add the `"notifications"` permission in the `manifest.json` file

Comment: thank you but i'm asking how to communicate with my mysql DB and count the number of entries for example (this number will appear using the chrome notification api).

Comment: I guess you have to first check if chrome notifications are turned on or not.

Comment: very importan! : do not forget to add the "notifications" permission in the manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the notification from the window object like that

and -- very importan! : do not forget to add the "notifications" permission in the manifest.json

```
    function init() {
    
    
    if (!window.Notification) {

        alert('notSupport');
    } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        console.log('grant notification')
        installNotification = createInstallNotification();

    } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        console.log('denied init notes')
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            console.log('ask init notes',permission)
            if (permission === 'granted') {

                installNotification = createInstallNotification();

            }else{
                alert('doNotDenied')
            }
        })

    }
    // end init
}
function createInstallNotification() {
    return new Notification('installSuccess', {
        body: 'text body'
        , tag: 'uniqe-numer-here'
    })
}
```