# How to not show duplicate Google Chrome notifications?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

From [this javascript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) I learnt how to make desktop notifications work in Google Chrome, and decided to implement this on my site.

So every time a certain something happens, I am making a notification show.

The problem is, that most of the time, the user has more than one window open, which can display notifications, causing duplicate notifications.

Is there a way which allows me to not show duplicate Google Chrome notifications?

Thanks.

Comment: can't you save them down in a list, and only show them sometimes?

Comment: @BottleofMilk No, as it is site-wide - that is that notifications can basically be triggered by any page, so I can't keep track of them.

Comment: I see. What about websockets?

Comment: @BottleofMilk Not particularly applicable for my situation.

Comment: You should send notifications with "collapse_key" set

Answer (score 4):

Using the same solution, solved it by adding a **tag** property onto my notification instantiation

```
var notification = new Notification('Notification Title', 
{
  icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
  body: "Hello Earth",
  tag:"uniqueTag"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue where in my Chrome Extension for Eye Rest would show a notification box every 20 minutes and if users don't close the notification box, 20 minutes later another would pop.
The way I went about it was to use a callback function with setTimeout to automatically close the notification bar after a given time.

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification('48x48.png',"Notification Title","Notification Body");
notification.show();
setTimeout(function(){
notification.cancel();
},2000);
```