# how to check if chrome notification appear using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i need to check whenever a notification appears or not in Google chrome using JavaScript.  i was trying to do so using `chrome.notifications.ondisplay` but i had no success. is there other way to do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example

I hope this will help you further.

Comment: i already checked this thread, but it refers to notification that i created, i want to catch the event of every notification that appear, for instance : translation notification..  but thanks anyway ;-)