# How to create an HTML5 Desktop pop-up/Display Area

Tags: c#, javascript, html, desktop-application, displayobject

I want to create a simple Desktop Notification App that behaves like the [Chrome Desktop Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example/) for some some reason my initial question was not well received, so I decided to just break my question down into components.   I typically only do web dev, so I know how most of the mechanics work but, I need some initial direction in how to create the display component.   So keeping it very simple, how can I create a border-less dialog box that consists of an HTML view.   I'll be continuing to dig into this myself as well but, I was hoping to draw on the experience of the community so that I can see the best practices in implementing this kind of UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try This example,

Email Popup notification Example
[Download link](http://gmailnotifier2.codeplex.com/)

Download the code and create what you want.

Comment: I appreciate what you shared here, but it's not really what I'm looking for.  That info bubble is a MS class that you can invoke to raise the bubble tool tip.  It only allows a short text string and usage of the 3 or 4 default icons (like error or warning).  It won't allow for the HTML5 aspect that I desire.  Maybe there is more in this package than I initially saw, and I will confirm that.  I'm pretty sure though that this is not the code sample I'm looking for.

Comment: It does have some cool features that it's nice to see their implementation of though.  So I do appreciate the share, I plan on learning some from this, so thank you!