# How to create a desktop notifications for your web application?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications

I've tried searching and surprisingly I couldn't find anything on this. I have seen a few web apps that have desktop applications. For instance in gmail you can go into the settings and enable desktop notifications and get an alert even if you don't have the browser open at all. Also, there is an app called "slack" that I have been playing around with and I somehow got desktop notifications enabled. Also, google hangouts gives me notifications every once in a while. I don't know if this is a google chrome thing, or if it is a mac specific thing. Does anyone have any idea how these apps are posting these notifications?

[image]

Is it a browser specific thing? A platform specific thing? Did I download some type of desktop app that I have forgotten about that is enabling these apps to do this? Has anyone else created a desktop alert for their web app and how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question asked -
[Chrome Desktop Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example).

From a front-end standpoint, there is EventSource for this, though you could also use websockets or polling (checking every few minutes/seconds).

[Event Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) and [Server-Sent Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events).