# Desktop notifications for Chat Widgets

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-extensions, livechat

I'm trying to develop chat application using Yii chat widget, I need to show incoming message as Desktop notification like skype notifications.

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiichat/
```

Please can anyone give me an idea to display desktop notifications for yii chat!!!

Comment: If you want to show OS-level notifications from a web application, I don't think this is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notify via the web browser. For this user has to grant the permission for your domain to notify. Als this doesn't work in all browsers. Here's a similar question [Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)