# $.ajax not working on mobile chrome - shows 404

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

In my web app im using `$.ajax` to get data from an api... it works in all browsers except for chrome on mobile devices... when I use chrome console to emulate (i choose galaxy as the device) and inspect the issue... It is clear that on mobile the $.agax url is returning 404 but if i copy that url to a new tab (not emulated) there is not a 404...

Here is the call I am making.

```
    // both of the following urls have the same results
    var api_url = "https://pmp.psft.co/api/v2/collections/" + collection_id + "/contents?access_token="+token_cookie;
    var api_url = '/collections/' + collection_id + '/contents.json';
    $.ajax({
        url : api_url,
        type : "get",
        async: false,
        data: {per_page: perPage, page: currentPage},
        success : function(collectionData) {
            build_collection(collectionData);
            console.log('success collection data');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error collection data');
        }
     });
```

you can see it for you self by going here: https://sod3_omar.pmp.psft.co/collection?handle=communications&lang=en&tag=oh... You will see that content will load on all browsers except for mobile chrome. Inspect on while emulating a galaxy in inspector tools to see the 404.

error trace:

```
    jquery.js:9664 GET https://pmp.psft.co/api/v2/collections/4ef6af98-f38c-440c-bc04-863e4d34332b…e6e27a3b01b9812b829fdde87d387d7eae50e304181224e2c456faff&per_page=6&page=1 404 (Not Found)
    send @ jquery.js:9664
    ajax @ jquery.js:9215
    get_collection @ collection.js:22
    which_collection @ collection.js:208
    (anonymous) @ collection.js:246
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace here.

Comment: i edited the question... Is that what you need? You can also duplicate the problem in your environment instructions are above. Thanks! @Phix

Comment: perhaps the server doesn't like "Android" in the user-agent string, because all android emulations fail the same way - in firefox as well by the way, so it's not a mobile chrome issue, it's an android browser issue by the look of it

Comment: that is good to know. I dont know how this fits yet but on my iPhone it does not work in chrome. Can you explain what you meant by the "server not liking..." I also think this might be api specific problem.