# How do I properly set a close timeout on desktop notifications created by the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout

I am working with desktop notifications for my web application using the standard [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification).  For the purposes of my initial development, I am using Google Chrome.  With Chrome, when a page creates a `Notification` object, the notification will stay on the desktop forever.

The `Notification` prototype does have a `.close()` method which allows for the closing of a notification that has been previously invoked.  I figured that this, in conjunction with the `setTimeout` function would make automatically dismissing notifications after a couple seconds a piece of cake.  I even found [a guide confirming](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140723183645-7167214-showing-notifications-from-the-browser-with-html5) my idea.

However, it seems that I am unable to get the scope of the notification to work properly with the `setTimeout` function, and the `.close()` method does not get called properly for each created notification.

Here is what I have tried (I used some code found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) as a starting point):

Button:

```
<button onclick="notifyMe()">
  Notify me! 
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
// request permission on page load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});

function notifyMe() {
  if (!Notification) {
    //alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('Notification');

    notification.onclick = function () {
        window.focus();
    };

    setTimeout(notification.close, 2000);
    // Result: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

    // also tried.....

    // setTimeout(notification.close(), 2000);
    // Result: notification stays open forever

    // setTimeout('notification.close', 2000);
    // Result: ReferenceError: notification is not defined

  }

}
</script>
```

I would appreciate it if anyone who has experience with this could help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I wrap that into a `function() {}` it works:

```
setTimeout(function() { notification.close() }, 2000);
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/drnz12n8/2/