# how to do popup's like facebook does in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, popup

Say I have facebook open in one tab and am currently active in another. If I get a notification on facebook I get a weird popup from the browser. Here's a picture:

[image]

Google does these same types of notifications when you get IM's. My question is...  how do they do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use Chrome's desktop notification feature.

Check out an example here:
[Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)

P.S: You have to allow a site to show you desktop notifications. You will get a prompt near the address bar in Chrome, the first time a site tries to show you desktop notification.