# Best way to implement audio notification in the latest Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, notifications, autoplay

Now that in the **latest Google Chrome** versions **[defers playback of autoplay media until the tab is foregrounded](https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/6PiJQqJzGqX)** , what would be the best way to create a sound notification for a chat message.

When the web page goes in a background tab, any sound played on that tab is deferred till that tab is selected, which is bad experience as the sound is essential for our application.

The temporary solution that we went with is by creating **[Desktop Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)**, with which we show cards at the corner of the screen. But again Chrome does not support custom sounds in Desktop notifications