# How to create Notification Alert like facebook without using chrome webstore?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

Facebook have done a great work in **Notification**.Usually we get desktop popup notification when we add the extensions from chrome webstore.But in facebook we can enable the extension without using chrome webstore.*Please see the image.*
[image]
How we can do like that ?

NB:I know the code for showing notification.I want to know how we can add the extension without using chrome webstore,see the given image;facebook done it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome desktop notification example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)

Comment: @Austin It is not a duplicate question.Please recheck my question :)

Answer (score 1):

This probably refers to [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web) feature of Chrome using the draft [Push API](http://w3c.github.io/push-api/), which is implemented using Service Workers and GCM.

The linked article contains a detailed example; it's too long to reproduce here.

> I want to know how we can add the extension without using chrome webstore,see the given image;facebook done it.

Facebook does not add an extension. What it does is adding a [Service Worker](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/), than can receive push messages and show notifications if the user agrees to allow Facebook to show them.

[This](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-03) is a good tutorial on the topic.