# Browser desktop notification handle onClose event

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

I'm just started using desktop notification in browsers to notify users about new tasks and events of tasks. But it's iportant to notify every user about every event, and it's iportant to never notify double.

I checked [this descktop notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) question and many others, but didn't find any way to handle the notification close event.

I just looking for something like this:

```
var n = new Notification(title, {body: msg, icon: url});
n.onClose(function() {
    // do something...
});
```

Is there any way in pure `JavaScript` or `jQuery` to handle the event when user close the notify box?

Comment: Not sure if it's been removed - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclose

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got it working using `addEventListener` instead of `onClose`:

```
let n = new Notification('title')
n.addEventListener('close', () => console.log('closed'))
```

I only took a quick looks at the mozilla docs and I'm a little confused for they say that there has been an `onClose` but it's been removed.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclose)