# Web Notification API example to notify everyday once

Tags: javascript, web-notifications

Im trying to use the web notification API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification) to show browser notification, something like the example of this link (in marked answer) [Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)

However, Im looking for something that will automatically show certain such notification on daily basis, on a particular time. Like i see such notification for facebook in chrome browser. Is that possible? how can i achieve that? I know there might some browser limitation, however i'll be happy if i can do that for chrome and firefox.

Comment: If you don't want to build everything from scratch you can use web services like https://pushpad.xyz Beside the Push API it also supports Safari

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the [Push API](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/), service workers, and some corresponding server infrastructure. That way, if users opt-in, you can wake up your service worker at a particular time and deliver a message to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Let me explore that way