# Cross-tab popout

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to show to a user a cross-tab message (send it rather to a browser than a specific site). The thing is:

- user opens site X
- user opens a new tab with site Y (and stays there)
- site X has an important message for user that should be red immediately
- message box has shown on tab with site Y but comes from site X

How to achieve that? Will that work for all browsers?

Comment: that would be a major browser security bug if you could, it just wouldn't make sense!

Comment: @Amin Jafari This is for sure possible, some restaurants shown that the order is ready or something, even if you are on other tab. How to achieve that?

Comment: you mean for example I can alert on google page from my website?

Comment: @Amin Jafari Exactly. Trully it could be even a browser plugin.

Comment: that's impossible, can you send me a link to one of those restaurants you're talking about? if it was possible then I could just send alert to all the tabs every one milliseconds and stop the user from using the browser!

Comment: @Amin Jafari https://pyszne.pl/ is example. If I order food there, and reading something on other tab, when they send order to me, I'm getting small popout on bottom-right informing me about that.

Comment: oh that is not an alert, that's google chrome's notification, try googling for "chrome notification" or take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example

Comment: @Amin Jafari Thanks. You should post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're looking for is **[google chrome's notification](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXyoatg7TNAhUCuxQKHQrrASkQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.chrome.com%2Fapps%2Fnotifications&usg=AFQjCNEvWdwCric7mP-jkm81bugs1Fkxaw)**

you might want to also take a look at **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner of the sites X and Y?

Comment: Nope, I'm the owner of site X, Y is some random site. Some restaurant provide that kind of box info, no matter what tab are you currently on.

Comment: this is not an answer! please remove it