# Read click event in desktop allow notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

[image]

Hello everyone,

I need to read the click event on press allow or block in above image, but I am unable to read the event.
Any help will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a working example of desktop notifications for Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari.
Try it live on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/ziwod/2/edit?html,js,output).

Solution ON:

[Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)

Big Tutorial:

https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-web-notifications-api/