# Send Chrome notification to offline user

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, desktop

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I'm confused with something on PHP/JS

I have the code from [Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example), and I am trying to work out how to send the user a notification when `<?php sendChat(); ?>` is triggered. I have that setup with chat fine, I'm trying to send the offline user a desktop notification when someone chats with them and I have not a clue how to do this. I store their username and IP in my database if it's at all useful.

**EDIT:** Instead of this, would it be possible to instantly send wherever they are on the site?

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: How can you possibly send anything to anyone that is offline? the IP address is the IP address the last time they were online, which can change - what you are proposing is not only impossible, it's also unpossible

Comment: I may not have made it clear. I mean, the way Facebook notifies you, whenever you receive a new instant message. @JaromandaX

Comment: you have to be logged in to facebook somehow - so you can't be offline for a start