# Desktop notification in Chrome 62+

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I want to use a [desktop notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) in Chrome version 67, but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me if there is an alternative to implement such a function in the current version of Chrome?

I use the script from the SO question "Chrome desktop notification example"(link above).
When I run it in Firefox, it is working. But in Chrome the notification does not appear. In the answers of that question was written, that the script doesn't work with Chrome v.62 or upper.

Maybe someone knows another possibility to make a notification which will run in Chrome 67?

Comment: "in Chrome the notification does not appear." 
Do you receive an error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a currently a bug in Chromium:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=852062

As a workaround, you can fire the Notification using the [`requestInteraction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification) option:

```
new Notification('hello', {requireInteraction: true})
```