# Chrome browser desktop notification

Tags: javascript, notifications, desktop

After updating Google chrome to version 75 the desktop notification stopped working, but it is working fine on Firefox, is there a way to fix this issue or any workaround to display the desktop notification? Thanks in advance.
Note the application is web application not chrome extension, below is a sample for the desktop notification

```
Notification.requestPermission();
new Notification ("Desktop notification example")
```

Comment: check following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example there might be some methods that will work for you!

Answer (score 2):

The new `Notification` spec is updated. You need to change it to a promise based syntax for notifications now. Code should be something like this:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) { 
   if(permission === 'granted') {
      new Notification ("Desktop notification example")
   } else {
      console.log('not granted')
   }

})
```

New specification is written [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission#Syntax)

Comment: Hi Shababb Karim I've tried your suggestion still getting the same issue

Comment: Have you cleared the cache for all time in chrome and checked whether the notification is disabled for that site?

Comment: Yes, I've used the Empty Cache and Hard Reload option from chrome still the same issue