# Notification in Closed tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a code that sends a message to a user who is subscribed to notifications
But if the tab with the site is closed, these notifications do not work, how can I make these notifications work even if the tab is closed?

```
notiSet(event) {

            function notifyMe() {
                function notifySend() {
                    let notification = new Notification (
                        "New post in site Name",
                        {
                            tag : "ache-mail",
                            body : "Lorem ipsum" + e,
                            icon : "http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico"
                        }
                    )
                }
                let e = 0
                setInterval( function () {
                    notifySend()
                    e++
                }, 1000)
            }
            if (process.client) {
                if (!("Notification" in window)) {
                    alert("Go to chrome or Mozilla")
                } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                    setTimeout(notifyMe, 2000)
                } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
                    Notification.requestPermission( function (permission) {
                        if (!("permission" in Notification)) {
                            Notification.permission = permission
                        }
                        if (permission === "granted") {
                            setTimeout(notifyMe, 2000)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `serviceWorker` to be able to send notification if tab is closed. See this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification).

and check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328513/5058682) answer help you.

Comment: Didn't understand
In the documentation you gave me
there is such an example
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
Do I need to create this file?

Comment: yes, you need to have a service worker for this to work.

Comment: I have Nuxt project added this sw.js file to static folder but browser returned error Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Comment: I am not very proficient with service worker. Even if i were, i would need to know where and how you are registering your service worker, as well as the exact error. Please update your question so that someone can help you accordingly!

Comment: I registered sw.js and put the notification code there

Comment: But i have error Failed to construct 'Notification': Illegal constructor.